# How to evaluate the following integral

Tags: probability

$$
\int \limits_{}^{} \frac  {e^{tz^2}e^{-z^2/2}}{\sqrt{2π} }dz
$$

I know that
 $$
\int \frac  {1}{\sqrt{2π} } e^{-z^2/2}  dz
$$ is the pdf of a standard normal distribution, but I'm not sure what to do with the $$e^{tz^2}$$

Comment: Second integral is not PDF, it is integral of PDF. What are limits of integration? Multiply in first integrand, then change of variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we note that for $t\ge 1/2$ the integral diverges.

For $t<1/2$, write $e^{tz^2}e^{-z^2/2}=e^{-(1-2t)z^2/2}$.  Then, substitute $z\to \sqrt{1-2t}\,\,z$.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{tz^2}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-(1-2t)z^2/2}\,dz\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{1-2t}x} e^{-z^2/2}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}dz\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}\Phi (x\sqrt{1-2t})
\end{align}$$

where $\Phi (x)$ is the cumulative normal distribution function given by

$$\Phi (x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz$$

We note that for $x\to \infty$, we have

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tz^2}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}\Phi (x\sqrt{1-2t})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}$$

Comment: so you let z=sqrt(1-2t)? I don't really follow the change of variable that you do.

Comment: @risdel The change of variable transforms $z$ into $z\sqrt{1-2t}$.  Note that I wrote $z\to z\sqrt{1-2t}$ and not $z=\sqrt{1-2t}$.  If it is better, we can use another "dummy" variable of integration and write "let $z=u/\sqrt{1-2t}$."  Then, after doing so, we can change the "dummy" from $u$ back to $z$.  Does that help?  And please let me know how else I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: I'm not sure how to simplify that answer to (1-2t)^(-1/2)

Comment: @risdel Is the upper limit supposed to be $\infty$?

Comment: yes, good work. do you think it would be possible to show how you went from the 3rd to 4th line though? (how you get the cdf?)

Comment: Thank you!!  Let me know how else I can help going forward.